# WHMCS: How to create a new DB using a Hook

Tags: php, mysqli, hook, whmcs

I'm wanting to automatically create a new DB when a new customer signs up via WHMCS. I'm attempting to use a hook to achieve this:

```
<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS"))
die("This file cannot be accessed directly");

function createDB($vars) {

  // connect to the MySQL server
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', '', 'port');

  // check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  // sql query with CREATE DATABASE
  $sql = "CREATE DATABASE `test_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";

  // Performs the $sql query on the server to create the database
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

  }
  else {
    echo 'Error: '. $conn->error; die;
  }
  $conn->close();
}

add_hook("AcceptOrder",1,"createDB");
```

Not quite sure if `AcceptOrder` is the proper hook or if I should do something like `AfterModuleCreate`. I've tried both but I seem to always get the following error:

> Connect failed: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading
>   inital communication packet', system error: 11

Comment: don't create a new connection, but use WHMCS functions :`require_once  __DIR__ . '/init.php';
require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/dbfunctions.php');
$res_create=full_query('CREATE DATABASE some_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci');`

Comment: @houssam Thanks for the reply, and that would create the DB on the new customer's account? I actually figured this out using a hook to create a new db / user in their cpanel but now I'm wondering if what I have isn't proper because I use connection

Comment: AcceptOrder will be executed for all Orders; https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/shopping-cart/#acceptorder 
it is difficult to find the 'serviceid' and 'userid'. it depends on your hosting; can your user create new DBs.
how to delete the DB if the user did not pay?
you need: https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/